# File in both KLM and user space

Tags: c, kernel-module

I remembering reading this concept somewhere. I do not remember where though.
I have a file say file.c, which along with other files I compile along with some other files as a library for use by applications.

Now suppose i compile the same file and build it with a Kernel module. Hence now the same file object is in both user space and kernel space and it allows me to access kernel data structures without invoking a system call. I mean i can have api's in the library by which applications can access kernel data structures without system calls. I am not sure if I can write anything into the kernel (which i think is impossile in this manner), but reading some data structures from kernel this way would be fine?

Can anyone give me more details about this approach. I could not find anything in google regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a conceptually flawed approach, unless I misunderstand what you're talking about.

If I understand you correctly, you want to take the same file and compile it twice: once as a module and once as a userspace program. Then you want to run both of them, so that they can share memory.

So, the obvious problem with that is that even though the programs come from the same source code, they would still exist as separate executables. The module won't be its own process: it only would get invoked when the kernel get's going (i.e. system calls). So by itself, it doesn't let you escape the system call nonsense.

A better solution depends on what your goal is: do you simply want to access kernel data structures because you need something that you can't normally get at? Or, are you concerned about performance and want to access these structures faster than a system call?

For (1), you can create a character device or a procfs file. Both of these allow your userspace programs to reach their dirty little fingers into the kernel.

For (2), you are in a tough spot, and the problem gets a lot nastier (and more insteresting). To solve the speed issue, it depends a lot on what exact data you're trying to extract.

Does this help?

Comment: Hey, It was to solve the overhead of context switch. As i read your reply I now see it clearly, as to what was wrong in my thinking. Procfs is the way yo go if i have to read the data. For anything else i have to go through the soft interrupt, i mean syscall.

Comment: For the overhead problem, it very much depends on what data you're trying to find. Specifically, how often does the data you're asking for change?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, the most common being what's called a Character Device, and the other being a Block Device (i.e. something "disk-like").

[Here's a guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN569) on how to create drivers that register chardevs.